# Spaces breaking img src in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, backslash

Basically the title.

I have a mysql query:

```
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $jsonData[] = $array;
}
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

A variable referencing a value that has spaces in it named "Remnant of Argus":

```
var pname = value.Pet_Name;
```

that is being used to insert the value into both a plaintext `<div>` and an image `style='background-image: url()`:

```
$("img#"+char).click(function(){
    $("#charlist").html(title
           +"<table style='background:#888' width='600px'>"
             +"<tr>"
               +"<td rowspan='4' height='150px' width='150px' style='background-image: "
                       +"url(/images/char/"+char+".png)'></td>"
               +"<td>Name: "+fname+" "+lname+"</td>"
               +"<td>Class: "+spec+" "+role+"</td>"
             +"</tr>"
             +"<tr>"
               +"<td>Race: "+race+"</td>"
               +"<td>Rank: "+rank+"</td>"
             +"</tr>"
             +"<tr>"
               +"<td>Height: "+height+"</td>"
               +"<td>Weight: "+weight+"</td>"
             +"</tr>"
             +"<tr>"
               +"<td>Age: "+age+"</td>"
               +"<td>Birthplace: "+birth+"</td>"
             +"</tr>"
           +"</table>"
           +"<table width='600px'>"
             +"<tr>"
               +"<td>Bio:<br />"+bio+"</td>"
             +"</tr>"
           +"</table>"
           +"Pets"
           +"<table class='"+pname+"' width='300px'>"
             +"<tr>"
               +"<td rowspan='2' height='150px' width='150px' style='background-image: "
                       +"url(/images/pets/"+pname+".png)'></td>"
               +"<td>Name: "+pname+"</td>"
             +"</tr>"
             +"<tr>"
               +"<td>Species: "+prace+"</td>"
             +"</tr>"
           +"</table>"
           +"<table width='300px'>"
             +"<tr>"
               +"<td rowspan='2' height='150px' width='150px' style='background-image: "
                       +"url(/images/battlepets/"+cname+".png)'></td>"
               +"<td>Name: "+cname+"</td>"
             +"</tr>"
             +"<tr>"
               +"<td>Species: "+crace+"</td>"
             +"</tr>"
           +"</table>");

    $("table.none").hide();
});
```

Everything shows up fine except for the image. I've added backslashes to both the filename and value and THEN it shows up fine. I've tried everything I can think of, to replacing the spaces in the MySQL call (just adds backslashes everywhere), tried replacing the character in my jQuery (either breaks it completely or just plain doesn't work), adding another variable for just this one instance and trying encodeURIComponent or replace to no avail, and I'm at my wit's end.

I was hoping to not have to add another column of values without spaces JUST for `background-image` source URL, but if that's what it comes down to, I'll just do it and say screw it.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong? If you need any other pertinent info, lemme know. The website is: http://wow.zenakrua.com/ and you click Windwalkers, then click the angry purple chick, middle of the second row.

Comment: You don't really have an image with the filename `Remnant of Argus.png` do you, you want to remove those spaces, or just replace them with something else or what. Just showing us what you've got, and what you want, would be a lot easier than posting an entire table in one line.

Comment: Anyway, you should stick to lowercase and no spaces in filenames, so `char.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase()`

Comment: As per another comment (I added backslashes to the filename and the value as a test, it wasn't spaces at the time):
It wasn't wrong, but I guess the backslashes were causing a loading issue. Changed to dashes, wow.zenakrua.com/images/battlepets/Remnant-of-Argus.png. Took hotlink protection off. Regardless, the behavior was the same before I put backslashes. I've tried + and - in place, still can't get it to replace them in the jquery.

What other info would you need? I can paste the whole thing, there's two files involved, a php mysql query and the actual page with the ajax and jquery.

Comment: Basically I can't have spaces in the file name or it doesn't load the image. But I use the same variable to provide the file name and the plaintext name (which shows up fine). So I have to use dashes or +, and I need to turn those into spaces after the json encode for JUST the image filename for it to show up since that's what the variable is looking to match to the value. As it is now, if I have dashes in the value, that's what shows up in the Name box, and that's what the filename has to be since both the img src and the Name box use the same value.

Comment: You generally should never uses spaces in a filename, I'd suggest using underscore `_`. Also, you should try to always keep the filenames lowercase, if you're testing on a windows machine, case doesn't matter, and then maybe you upload your code to a webserver running linux, which is case-sensitive, and you'll have lots of issues, that's why you want lowercase filenames only. To do that, just replace the spaces with a regex `char.replace(/\s/g, '_').toLowerCase()`

Comment: Would that go on the variable or elsewhere?

Comment: `... +"url(/images/pets/" + char.replace(/\s/g, '_').toLowerCase() + ".png)'></td>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That image doesn't exist. If it did, you would be able to access it using this URL on the browser:

wow.zenakrua.com/images/battlepets/Remnant%20of%20Argus.png

The image name is either wrong, or you need to change the permissions on it.

Comment: It wasn't wrong, but I guess the backslashes were causing a loading issue. Changed to dashes, http://wow.zenakrua.com/images/battlepets/Remnant-of-Argus.png. Took hotlink protection off.

Regardless, the behavior was the same before I put backslashes. I've tried + and - in place, still can't get it to replace them in the jquery.

Comment: Can you add an image with the name Remnant of Argus.png (i.e. with spaces instead of the dashes, and no backslashes) so I can try to debug the issue? Or do you just need a way to change the dash to a space now so that the name appears correctly in the text?

Comment: That's exactly it. Just need the name in the name box to have the dashes replaced with spaces. I tried it in the mysql query but I could only get it to replace everything, not just the one. It's almost as if I can't change the json after the fact.

Comment: Add the following line under "var pname = value.Pet_Name;"  var display_name = pname.replace(/-/g, " ")   This will replace all instances of the dash with a space, then use the display_name variable instead of the pname variable in the name box. Would that solve it?

Comment: Nope, tried that previously actually, just a little different. Doesn't work. Also tried replacing pname with the actual value, no dice.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you replaced the line: "<td>Name: "+pname+"</td>" with the hardcoded value "<td>Name: Remnant of Argus</td>" and it didn't work?

Comment: var display_name = pname.replace(/-/g, " ") works. Turns out I was messing with the wrong variable.

Comment: It also works in the .html() as pname.replace(/-/g, " "), which is what I've decided on, so as to avoid extra one-use variables.